# iOS: present view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, presentviewcontroller

I'm using the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method to go to another view controller.

This is my code:

```
AddTaskViewController *add = [[AddTaskViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code goes to the other `UIViewController` but the other controller is empty. I've always been using storyboards but now I need this to be done in code.

Comment: This is not an Xcode question. Also, I couldn't deduce what you mean by "the other controller is nothing", so I left it intact.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard, you probably shouldn't be using `alloc` and `init` to create a new view controller. Instead, look at your storyboard and find the *segue* that you want to perform; it should have a unique identifier (and if not, you can set one in the right sidebar).

Once you've found the identifier for that segue, send your *current* view controller a `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` message:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

This will cause the storyboard to instantiate an AddTaskViewController and present it in the way that you've defined for that segue.

---

If, on the other hand, you're not using a storyboard at all, then you need to give your AddTaskViewController some kind of user interface. The most common way of doing so is to initialize the controller with a nib: instead of just calling `init`, you'll call `-initWithNibName:bundle:` and provide the name of a .xib file that contains your add-task UI:

```
AddTaskViewController *add = [[AddTaskViewController alloc]
                              initWithNibName:@"AddTaskView" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

(There are other (less common) ways of getting a view associated with your new view controller, but this will probably present you the least trouble to get working.)

Comment: If it is combined with a button its work. but is not combined.

Comment: So how do you "un-present" the new view controller in the non-storyboard scenario? I'm googling around trying to find something similar to unwindForSegue:towardsViewController:

Comment: Actually, I just found "dismissViewController" which I think is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Answer (score 31):

If you are using Storyboard and your "add" viewController is in storyboard then set an identifier for your "add" viewcontroller in settings so you can do something like this:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NameOfYourStoryBoard" 
                                                     bundle:nil];
AddTaskViewController *add = 
           [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentifier"];

[self presentViewController:add 
                   animated:YES 
                 completion:nil];
```

if you do not have your "add" viewController in storyboard or a nib file and want to create the whole thing programmaticaly then appDocs says:

> If you cannot define your views in a storyboard or a nib file, override the loadView method to manually instantiate a view hierarchy and assign it to the view property.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set storyboard Id from storyboard identity inspector

```
 AddTaskViewController *add=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard_id"];
 [self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

your code :

```
 AddTaskViewController *add = [[AddTaskViewController alloc] init];
 [self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this code can goes to the other controller , but you get a new viewController , not the controller of your storyboard, you can do like this :

```
AddTaskViewController *add = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourStoryboardID"];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is

```
AddTaskViewController * add = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addID"];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in Swift:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This just loads a blank UIViewController

Comment: of course it does. You have to replace it with your own viewcontroller, or add some sort of color or objects inside the view of uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
NextViewController *nextView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextView"];
[self presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LandingScreenViewController *nextView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextView"];
[self presentViewController:nextView animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: To [reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11794904): if the answer is bad but is an answer (like this is), don't recommend deletion: downvote! See [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007). This is an answer. You may not agree with it, but it is an attempt to answer the question.