# cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton WHAT IS NEXT?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Still fairly new to iOS. I've managed to write a basic app to display a list/table of documents. I've included:

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;

which display a blue i within a circle button which I guess can be used to perform some sort of action.

What I'd like to do now is, upon click, to display a subsequent screen with information about the document, buttons, add, delete functions, date, file size etc...

Is this done via segue or some other method?

Being a novice I am not sure what is/are the next step(s). If I know what steps I must take in order to get to next scree(s) I can search the net for example of how to do any given step.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, welcome to the iOS developing community!

In order to do this, I would use a segue to a detail view that you can design. When you select a row in your table using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you would set an @property to the object in your array that was selected: self.selectedObject = self.tableviewarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row; Then in the prepareForSegue method you can get the destination view controller and do destinationViewController.myObject = self.selectedObject; Now the detail view knows what object to display info for!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58716/discussion-between-georgeofthejungle-and-jacob).

Answer (score 3):

The accessoryButton triggers it's own delegate method, distinct from the row selection, called:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Add that method to your delegate, and then do a vc transition.  There are several ways to do that transition, most of the common ones are [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152746/ios-present-view-controller-programmaticallly)...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement the delegate method

`-tableView:(UITableView*) didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)`

and handle the row tap in that callback accordingly.

An example would be like this:

```
-tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    YourObject *theModelForRow = [_itemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    YourViewController *someNewViewController = [YourViewController viewControllerWithModel:theModelForRow];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:someNewViewController animated:YES];
}
```